# using of javascript or python in SSIS?

Tags: javascript, python, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I am planning to use of javascript or python in SQL SERVER INTEGRATION SERVICES (SSIS ETL).Does it has to be utilised using the execute process task.Is there any other way to replace the existing script task with python and or javascript {The current script task/components only support Vb/C# :(    ) .Please share your thoughts

Comment: If you ever manage to update to SQL Server 2016 you can execute python via a stored procedure. Until then I think you are left with [execute process task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41929392/how-do-i-run-a-py-file-from-execute-process-task). I do not know about JS

Comment: Thats great! You mean we can execute Python via SQL Stored Procedures!

Comment: Yes, but I was wrong about the version - it will be out in SQL Server 2017 soon. Check out [more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/python/architecture-overview-sql-server-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can only use VB/C# in the script task.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/script-task

> Script Language
>
> Select the scripting language for the task, either Microsoft Visual Basic or Microsoft Visual C#.

Comment: Thank you .I did use c#/vb.net.Wondering about Pyhon/JS in script componet

Answer (score 1):

With the 1.9 release of COZYROC SSIS+ (a commercial third-party suite of useful SSIS extensions), you can now use JavaScript as a scripting language in SSIS. For more info, see https://www.cozyroc.com/ssis/javascript

Disclaimer: I am working for COZYROC and have been involved in the development of the JS support.